# Opengl quad tesselation, I need it to be more regular. I need it to be image on left, rather than that on right

Tags: opengl, tesselation

[image]

I am trying to tesselate a quad to have a regular grid pattern as shown in quad on the left of the image. But what I am getting from the opengl tesselation is irregular pattern as you can see on the quad on right of image. Is there a way that I can output regular grid from tesselation just as that of quad on left of image?

Comment: Short answer: No. See [Tessellation - Qauds](https://www.khronos.org/opengl/wiki/Tessellation#Quads), the edges are depending on the implementation of the graphics driver and GPU and are not specified.